# Manually executing a CRON - Confused about params

Tags: linux, debian, bash, shell

I have this code snippet:

```
$CUSER=tim
$APPDIR=/var/www/testing
$APPVENV=/var/www/testing/ven
cat > $APPDIR/cronfile << EOF
PWD=$APPDIR/$CUSER
PATH=$APPVENV/bin:\$PATH
0 2 * * * testapp search newsite
EOF
crontab $APPDIR/cronfile
```

It seems to work but I'm really confused about how I would try to run this manually. What does this expand to if I wanted to run it from a command from shell?

I tried something like this but it didn't work :(

```
cd /var/www/testing/ven 
testapp search newsite
```

Comment: Try to run "this manually". "this" is is not the the "this" in "this code snippet" from what you tried. Or are you trying the wrong thing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you are adding `$APPVENV/bin` to your path in order to run this from `cron` you should use:

```
cd /var/www/testing/ven/tim
/var/www/testing/ven/bin/testapp search newsite
```

Answer (score 1):

The Path is in `$APPVENV/bin`, so you need to run

```
cd /var/www/testing/ven/bin
testapp search newsite
```